# ¿Cómo mandar un formulario por email? (utilizando xampp)

Tags: php

Me da este error

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port
>   25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use
>   ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\LF\html\sugerencias.php on line 17

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $nombre=$_POST['name'];
                $correo=$_POST['email'];
                $mensaje=$_POST['mensaje'];
  $enviar = 'learningfriends17@gmail.com';
$asunto = 'Sugerencia';
$header = 'From: ' . $correo;
$msjCorreo = "Nombre: $nombre\n E-Mail: $correo\n Mensaje:\n $mensaje";

    if (mail($enviar, $asunto, $msjCorreo, $header)){
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias.');
window.history.go(-1);

</script>";
} else {
echo 'Falló el envio';
}
}

?>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**como configurar xampp para enviar correos desde un localhost**

Como configurar xampp para enviar correos desde un localhost
Para poder enviar email desde localhost es necesario configurar el php.ini  y sendmail.ini con una cuenta SMTP para gestionar los correos electrónicos.
Los primero es ingresar al php.ini y buscar la línea [mail function] aquí des comentaremos sendmail_path ingresando el path de donde este instalado nuestro sendmail para mi caso me quedaría asi.

```html
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
; SMTP = localhost
; smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost

; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (1): If XAMPP is installed in a base directory with spaces (e.g. c:\program filesE:\xampp) fakemail and mailtodisk do not work correctly.
; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (2): In this case please copy the sendmail or mailtodisk folder in your root folder (e.g. C:\sendmail) and use this for sendmail_path.  
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
sendmail_path = "\"E:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the E:\xampp\mailoutput folder
;sendmail_path="E:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header=Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
mail.log = "E:\xampp\php\logs\php_mail.log"
```

lo segundo ingresamos al  sendmail.ini  que lo podríamos encontrar donde se instalo nuestro servidor xampp.

Y debe quedarnos algo como lo siguiente;
auth_username=carlos@ingenieroweb.com.co

- auth_password=miclave
- smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
- smtp_port=587
- smtp_ssl=auto

con esto ya deberíamos poder enviar correos desde nuestro localhost, espero les sea de utilidad.

Igualmente aqui esta una pregunta identica pero en stackoverflow  en ingles:

[La pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

[Fuente del tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/zfwxvw/send-mail-from-localhost-with-xampp)

Aunque si estas haciendo pruebas de un proyecto tuyo o de negocios te recomendaria un servidor gratuito como hostinger.