# Problema con función mail() de php

Tags: php, email, xampp

Estoy haciendo una pequeña prueba para intentar enviar un correo electrónico a través de php pero no me está funcionando. Aclarar que no tengo ni idea de SMTPs ni configuración de servidores ni nada de esto.

Tengo instalado el xampp.

Este es mi código HTML para que al pulsar un botón llame a un archivo en localhost que enviará el correo:

```
function enviarCorreo(){            
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "enviarCorreo.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Y este es el código del archivo php:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: La prueba. < mi_correo_electronico@hotmail.com >\r\n";

$resultado = mail("correo_electronico_destino@hotmail.com", "Este es el título del mail.", "Este es el contenido del mail.", $headers);

if($reusltado){
    echo "EXITO";
}else{
    echo "Ha habido algun fallo.";
}
```

En el `$headers`, donde aparece "mi_correo_electronico@hotmail.com" ahi tengo puesto mi correo electrónico, y en `$resultado`, donde aparece "correo_electronico_destino@hotmail.com" es la dirección de correo donde quiero enviar el mail (ambos correos son míos pero distintos. Son reales).

Luego, en la llamada ajax, cuando muestro la información que recibo del servidor me muestra el siguiente mensaje de error:

> mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at localhost port 25, verify your SMTP and smtp_port setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

En php.ini me aparece que tengo la siguiente confiruación:

`[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=25`

¿Que puede estar ocurriendo? Supongo que será seguramente alguna configuración del xampp pero no tengo ni idea de cual.

Saludos.

Comment: La función `mail()` tal y como la tienes configurada espera que tengas un servidor de correo instalado en tu máquina. Procura usar [`PHPMailer`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) si quieres evitar dicha instalación y, como plus, gestionar mejor el contenido del mensaje (codificación, cabeceras, archivos adjuntos, etc).

Comment: Perfecto. Lo probaré. Muchísimas gracias @OscarGarcia

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo mandar un formulario por email? (utilizando xampp)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/81211/c%c3%b3mo-mandar-un-formulario-por-email-utilizando-xampp). Hay muchas preguntas sobre el mismo tema [ver aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=mail%28%29%3A+Failed+to+connect+to+mailserver+at+localhost+port+25).

Comment: Con PHPMailer ha funcionado a la perfección. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

La función ini_set() http://php.net/manual/es/function.ini-set.php permite cambiar la configuración en tiempo de ejecución de tu php.init.
Si cambiar la configuración smtp podrás enviar el correo.

```
ini_set('SMTP', 'host_de_tu_servidor_de_correos');//host_de_tu_servidor_de_correos ejemplo smtp.gmail.com
ini_set('smpt_port', 'puerto_tu_servidor_de_correos');//puerto_tu_servidor_de_correos ejemplo 443.
```

Te dejo el listado de propiedades modificables, con la clave para modificarlas y el valor por defecto que tienen: http://php.net/manual/es/ini.list.php